# How to make Oracle XE dump and roll it with shell script

Tags: import, oracle11g, export, dump

I have one running instance of Oracle XE. There are some users created and tables.

I need a way to export or make a dump of all I have there, and be able to roll it on clean installation of Oracle XE in automatic manner (from unix bash script).

Can someone help please?

Comment: EXPDP/IMPDP if it is available with XE ( not sure ).

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes, they are. But they do export and do it for particular user. I want to export or import all users in the table.